# Campo texto nao pega valor asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net, mvc, razor

Possuo um campo texto em meu sistema chamado `NomeEspecificacao`, porem quando eu preencho qualquer valor nele, sempre é retornado null na minha Action, ou seja, nunca vem a palavra que escrevo no campo texto.

Código da View:

```
model SEMA.Fiscalizacao.Presentation.Web.Models.IncluirMaterialViewModel
@{
    var disabled = Model.Consultar ? "disabled=\"disabled\"" : "";
}

@{
    if (Model.Consultar)
    {
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NomeMaterialCategoria, "Categoria")
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.NomeMaterialCategoria, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @maxlength = 50, disabled } })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
    else
    {
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NomeMaterialCategoria, "Categoria")
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.NomeMaterialCategoria, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @maxlength = 50 } })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
}


@Html.Partial("_SelectMutipleUnidadesMedida", Model)

<hr class="hr-text" data-content="Especificação da Categoria" />

@{
    if (Model.Consultar)
    {
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                @{
                    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Model.NomeMaterial) && Model.NomeMaterial.Length > 0)
                    {
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.NomeEspecificacao, new { @class = "form-control margin-bottom", @maxlength = 50 })
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.NomeEspecificacao, new { @class = "form-control margin-bottom", @maxlength = 50, disabled })
                    }
                }


            </div>
        </div>
    }
    else
    {
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.NomeEspecificacao, new { @class = "form-control margin-bottom", @maxlength = 50 })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 text-right margin-bottom">
                <input type="submit" id="AdicionarEspecificacao" value="Adicionar" class="btn btn-default" name="command:IncluirEspecificacoes:1">
                <button type="submit" id="AdicionaMultiplasEspecificacoes" class="btn btn-default" name="command:AbrirMultiplasEspecificacoes">
                    Adicionar Múltiplos
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
}


@if (Model.ListaMaterialCategoriaEspecificacoes != null && Model.ListaMaterialCategoriaEspecificacoes.Count > 0)
{
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            @Html.Partial("_ListaEspecificacaoCategoria", Model)
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Action  que retorna null na model:

```
[HttpPost]
        [CommandName("Alterar", "command:IncluirEspecificacoes:{index}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult> IncluirEspecificacoesAlterarAsync(IncluirMaterialViewModel model)
        {
            var tipoEspc = Convert.ToInt32(RouteData.Values["index"]);


            if (tipoEspc == 1)
            {

                    AdicionaEspecificacao(model, model.NomeEspecificacao);
            }

            if (tipoEspc == 2)
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(model.NomeEspecificacaoMultiplo))
                {
                    model.ModalEspecificacoes = true;
                    ErrorMessage = Mensagens.UC027_MSG007;

                    model.CodigoUnidadeMedidaPermitidaUsoSimpViewModel
               .AddRange(model.ListaUnidadeMedidasPermitidasParaUso.Select(x => x.CodigoUnidadeMedida));

                    await PreencherUnidadesMedidaViewModelIncluir(model);
                    await AdicionaUnidadeMedidaPermitidasParaUso(model);

                    return PartialView("_Incluir", model);
                }
                else
                {
                    AdicionaEspecificacao(model, model.NomeEspecificacaoMultiplo);
                }
            }


            model.CodigoUnidadeMedidaPermitidaUsoSimpViewModel
                .AddRange(model.ListaUnidadeMedidasPermitidasParaUso.Select(x => x.CodigoUnidadeMedida));

            await PreencherUnidadesMedidaViewModelIncluir(model);
            await AdicionaUnidadeMedidaPermitidasParaUso(model);
            return PartialView("_Incluir", model);
        }
```

[image: Imagem do campo preenchido]

[image: Resultado vindo na Model logo após clicar em "Adicionar"]

Alguem pode me ajudar?

Ps: adicionado imagens para uma melhor análise do problema.

Comment: Como fica a requisição quando você envia o formulário? Este campo está presente nela?

Comment: sim está presente

Comment: Adicionei imagens para mostrar o que ta acontecendo....

Comment: é somente para editar. Para inclusão funciona...

Answer (score 1):

Não desabilite o controle, coloque como readonly e aplique estilos CSS pra parecer desabilitado.

Campos desabilitados não são postados. Por isso o DefaultModelBinder não consegue preencher a propriedade correspondente do seu model.

Comment: eu comentei a linha var disabled = Model.Consultar ? "disabled=\"disabled\"" : ""; e retirei todos os "disabled" dos campos. Continua como null na model. Não pega valores preenchidos no campo.

Comment: Adicionei imagens para mostrar o que ta acontecendo....

Comment: ta numa partial view esse código, nao sei se tem algo a ver....